# C# - DataTable.Select() 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

Tags: c#, winforms, select, datatable, datatables

I'm getting a String was not recognized as a valid DateTime exception when trying to select values from a datatable.

Code:

```
//get start and end dates from datetime pickers
string startDate = dateTimeStart.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string endDate = dateTimeEnd.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

//add picked dates to expression
selectExpression = selectExpression + " AND Date >= #" + startDate + "# AND Date <= #" + endDate + "#";

//copy selected events to the filtered results datatable
dtFiltered = dt.Select(selectExpression).CopyToDataTable();
```

When I execute the code my expression is:

```
"Name = 'Test' AND Event = 'open' AND Date >= #13/03/2017# AND Date <= #13/03/2017#"
```

So why does it not like this?
Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Afaik it's `#03/13/2017#`, so month first, since there is no 13th month you get this exception.

Comment: Let's say it once again. Use Parametrized queries and you won't have this problems

Comment: @Pikoh OP seems to be using DataTable. There is no way to use parameters.

Comment: @Pikoh: well, here is no database query so he can't use it. But he could use `Linq`: `var query=dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>r.Field<DateTime>("Date")>=dateTimeStart.Value && r.Field<DateTime>("Date")<=dateTimeEnd.Value);`

Comment: @IvanStoev you are right. I overlooked it

Comment: Nice, thank you @TimSchmelter! so simple, I live in the UK so we use dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, that's the best way. What I meant is that handling DateTimes as strings is error-prone all times

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx): *All literal expressions must be expressed in the **invariant** culture locale*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik it's #03/13/2017#, so month first, since there is no 13th month you get this exception.

```
string startDate = dateTimeStart.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
string endDate = dateTimeEnd.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Parsing Literal Expressions: All literal expressions must be expressed
>   in the **invariant culture locale**.

You could also use LINQ, then you have compile time safety and can use any .NET code:

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r=> r.Field<DateTime>("Date") >=‌ ​dateTimeStart.Value 
            && r.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= dateTimeEnd.Value); 
if(query.Any())
    dtFiltered = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Note: i guess you want to include the whole `dateTimeEnd`-day. Then you need:

```
            && r.Field<DateTime>("Date") < dateTimeEnd.Value.Date.AddDays(1));
```